# "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in" when retrieving data from select

Tags: javascript, laravel

I will display data in the table, but there is an error "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in". url successfully GET action, but when displaying data in the table an error occurs. this is my javascript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#kategori').on('change', function(e){
                var id = e.target.value;
                $.get('/khs/khs_semester'+id, function(data){
                    console.log(id);
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#khs').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(index, element){
                        $('#khs').append("<tr><td>"+element.kode_mk+"</td><td>"+element.nama_mk+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+element.semester+"</td></tr>");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is my Controller.

```html
public function merkAjax($id){
        if($id==0){
            $terpilih = \DB::table('khs')
                        ->join('matakuliah','matakuliah.kode_mk','=','khs.kode_mk')
                        ->join('dosen','dosen.nidn','=','khs.nidn')
                        ->where('khs.nim',$nim)
                        ->where('khs.semester','1')
                        ->get();
        }else{
        $terpilih =  \DB::table('khs')
                      ->join('matakuliah','matakuliah.kode_mk','=','khs.kode_mk')
                      ->join('dosen','dosen.nidn','=','khs.nidn')
                      ->where('khs.nim',$nim)
                      ->where('khs.semester',$id)
                      ->get();
        }
        return $terpilih;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `in` operator only works on objects.

could be the data you are sending needs parsing (i.e a stringified json).

try parsing your data `JSON.parse(data)`

`$.each(JSON.parse(data), function(index, element){...})`

Comment: i'm try and error :

 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

 why?

Comment: @KhaizBadaruTammam it means that your data isn't json string. could you please post your data received in response before doing the each loop?

Comment: Thanks, Solved. I'm forget to to write the code / before +id